# Command runs in terminal, but not in rc.local?

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi

Tried some of the previous Stackoverflow solutions to this problem, none worked so I apologize in advance for making another thread with a very similar title to previous ones
.
I have two lines of code that need to execute on startup on my Raspberry Pi, so I decided to put them both into rc.local as such:

sudo python /home/pi/lightshowpi/py/app.py

sudo python /home/pi/lightshowpi/py/NgrokStartScript.py &

The top one opens a Flask-Ask script, the NgrockStartScript opens a server. When I startup my machine, my server executes no problem, but my app.py script doesn't run (as when I ask Alexa for it, it gives me a problem with skill error).

However, when I type the first line exactly into terminal and hit enter, the whole thing runs without a problem. I've tried putting an "&" next to the app.py line in rc.local to see if that would solve it, no luck.

Here's a link to the contents of the problematic script if this would make any difference: https://gist.github.com/colinwarn/c7d64d6596d9074fa45a371f08f3ae94

Legitimately have no idea where to go here, any ounce of help would mean the world to me.

Comment: Call python for a service not equal to "Call SH for starting python app", create a `bash` for get to path and run python code, don't forget adding directory in your python code(work with relative paths(not absolute)). Service isn't sample application, allways required `isAlive`, `Resource_Status`, `hardware`, check !

Comment: A trick : Start app `time.sleep(60)` ,`check hardware`IP is OK + disk/ram is OK than run your code...

Comment: @dsgdfg don't you mean absolute not relative paths?  Also I don't think it's a path problem as my NgrokStartScript runs fine, and it's in the exact same folder as my app.py script (the one giving me problems.


Tried the time.sleep trick, created another file that would os.system execute my python script, but before that I have the script sleep for 50 seconds.  I made said script the one to work on boot, didn't seem to work.


Will give the bash script suggestion a try.